# Derivation of the coherence length of the light coming from a star

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, astronomy, coherence

Consider a star perceived under an angle $\alpha$ from the earth. In the Hanbury Brown Twiss experiment, they say that the coherence length $L_{coh}$ of this light is given by
$$
L_{coh}= \frac{\lambda}{\alpha}
$$
where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the incoming light . So they measure the coherence length of the light and use it to determine $\alpha$, and from it can say what is the diameter of a star.

I tried to wrap my head around this problem but I couldn't find a derivation of this relation. Can you please provide me a hint on how to derive it or give me a derivation? Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you provide a link to the reference where you got this equation from?